# syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_num_rows'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

This is my code:

```
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE usnername='$un' '");
$check = mysqli_num_rows ( $u_check );
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socially\index.php on line 27

I can't fix this, i am using a tutorial to help me do something, and this is what he typed. I really want to fix it so i can continue what I want to do; I'm doing the database because I am making a login and register form. Please help.  When I type `$check = mysqli_num_rows ( $u_check );` into the sql tab in phpmyadmin, i get this message:

Static analysis:

> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>   Unexpected character. (near "$" at position 0)
>   Unexpected character. (near "$" at position 25)
>   Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "$" at position 0)
>
> SQL query:
>   $check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check)
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '$check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check)' at line 1

Comment: Aren't you mixing mysql_* with mysqli_ *?

Comment: And also confusing PHP and SQL, it seems.

Comment: I see a typo in your first line: `username` vs `usnername`. That could throw and error and result in a boolean value.

Comment: I don't really know PHP, but it seems like that tutorial is encouraging a coding style that permits SQL injection (e.g., "username='$un'"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `MySQL` with `MySQLi`

If you are using `MySQL`:

```
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE usnername='$un'");
$check = mysql_num_rows ($u_check);
```

If you are using `MySQLi`:

```
$u_check = mysql_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE usnername='$un'");
$check = mysqli_num_rows ($u_check);
```

*(Replace `$con` with your database parameter if you're using `MySQL`)*

It's also possible that you meant `username` in your query rather than `usnername`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.

Comment: I have been getting another error. When i type this: else
{
    $pswd = md5($pswd);
    $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ', '$un', '$fn', '$ln', '$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
} I get an error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socially\index.php on line 39

Comment: Can you post line 39?

Comment: Your error points to line 39 on index.php. Could you paste that line here?

Comment: So paste the else line somewhere else? I moved it down a bit, still got an error. Do you want the line that i'm getting an eror on pasted in here? I got you

Comment: Have any way i could send you a screenshot? Here's the code that the tutorial showed me to use: else
{
    if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){}
    echo "Your password be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}
else
{
    $pswd = md5($pswd);
    $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ', '$un', '$fn', '$ln', '$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
} Here's the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socially\index.php on line 39

Comment: You can't start with an else statement - is that the complete code?

Comment: No. That's the two else statements

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand your code posted in a comment. Why not create a new question and link it to me?

Comment: I would send a screenshot if i could

Comment: How would i do that? Its says i can't ask another question

Comment: Do have some sort of gmail?

Answer (score -1):

Replace:

```
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE usnername='$un' '");
```

With:

```
$u_check = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE usnername = $un");
```

You always put variables in double quotes, otherwise the script thinks what you are writing is a string, not a variable.

Comment: What about $check = mysql_num_rows ( $u_check ); When i just paste the correction in you gave me, i keep getting an error message: 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socially\index.php on line 26

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Socially\index.php on line 27

Comment: That SQL is invalid, the `$un` is a string so it needs to be quoted when it gets to the DB. `mysqli_query` requires a connection string.